# Is JavaScript necessary to learn ,to use all HTML 5 features?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, html, canvas

These days I am learning **HTML5** new element where I read that the `canvas` tag is only a container for graphics, **you must use a script to actually paint graphics**. 
so I want to know that **Is JavaScript necessary to learn** ,to use all HTML 5 features?

If yes than for which tags of **HTML5** , JavaScript knowledge will be needed?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use all HTML 5 features then, yes, you have to learn javascript because some of them rely on javascript like [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) and the WebSocket API.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are various features of HTML5 which are not JavaScript dependent; for example, new tags like `<article>`, `<header>`, `<footer>`, etc.

On your particular example of the `canvas`, you don't even need to access it through JavaScript - [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org) makes is a great for programmers and non-programmers alike and is very easy to start with.

Answer (score 0):

No, Javascript is not needed to learn HTML 5. In fact, it is advisable to separate Javascript from HTML 5. Naturally, Javascript can alter the structure and it is a good thing to be fluent in Javascript, but you can implement only the structure and a teammate might be responsible of the scripts.

Let's suppose you need a `canvas` like this:

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

Let's suppose further, that you need to draw a rectangle, like this:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
```

Nobody prevents your team of implementing a .js file where the js code is included and of you using a script tag inside your structure, having the `src` attribute pointing to the .js file.

Long story short: You do not need to learn or understand Javascript to be able to work with HTML 5, but it is a nice thing to know. You need Javascript to develop a website though, so at least a basic knowledge about the language would not hurt.